# Is there a way to show emojis in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, emoji

I have various Django `CharField`s in my app that users use emojis to fill in. When I look in the admin, it looks like blank entries even though they show up properly as emojis on the app frontend.

How can I get emojis to show up in the admin interface so I can see what users have entered?

Answer (score 1):

Emojis are encoding using *utf8mb4*, so you have to set a connection that uses that encoding. Add this line inside the DATABASES block to your `settings.py` file:

```
'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
```

You can learn more about emoji's support in Django Admin panel in this [blog post](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/03/31/using-emojis-in-django-model-fields).